# Redefine Terminal does not work when starting VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can live with it, but...

I have changed the terminal from PowerShell to git bash in the settings:

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
```

This does its job. When I create a new terminal, it is git bash by default.

However, when I start Visual Studio Code, it opens with a PowerShell terminal. (All new terminals are git bash terminals.)

Comment: I had that too, but after a reloads and restarts it seems to be consistently only git bash now.

Comment: I might have clicked the `+` button to open a git bash terminal, then deleted the PowerShell terminal, then exited vscode and restarted.

Comment: Now it works! I decided to reboot my Windows machine. When coming back, VS Code had updated from 1.56 to 1.57. So, it either was the reboot or the upgrade. Thanks a lot for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

To set the default terminal in VS Codem , you should follow this steps:

- Open VS Code
- Press CTRL+Shift+P / ⇧⌘P and search for terminal select default shell
- Make your selection and press enter (In my case I chose Git Bash)

All of your new terminals will now default to your choice

I hoped this helped you.

Comment: Your steps result in the settings entry that I mentioned in my question. This changes the default for new terminals, but when I start VS Code is still has the first terminal as PowerShell.

Comment: yes it's working on my side and bash is my default terminal now , have you the latest version of VSCODE ?

Comment: My Vscode version is 1.57.0 the latest one

Comment: See my comment above. It might have been the version.